# chromium-browser version 28 for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, chromium

recently chromium-browser package in Ubuntu 12.04 was updated to version 30.0.1599.114 for my installation. Before that update I had version 28.0.1500.52 installed on my system. Together with this system I was running a VLC plugin in my chromium-browser and with the new version 30 this plugin crashes all the time.

The best way to go is of course to make the plugin work with version 30 of chromium-browser but right now I do not have the time for that. The way forward for me right now is to revert the chromium-browser to version 28 again in order to get my system up and running again with my VLC plugin.

I can't figure out where to find the package chromium-browser 28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.12.04.2, can anyone help me? What is the proper way to install an old version of chromium-browser?

Thanks,
/Peter

Comment: Version 29 should be available, have you tried with this?

Comment: Yes, that has become my solution. Installing version 29 of chromium-browser made VLC plugin to work.

Answer (score 0):

Install It with
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall google-chrome-stable=28`

From your terminal

Comment: I am using the package chromium-browser.
Trying "sudo apt-get install --reinstall chromium-browser=28" gives:  

"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '28' for 'chromium-browser' was not found"

Comment: Give me time I will figure it out